# rake aborted! uninitialized constant Rails::SubTestTask

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

I'm updating to Rails 4 using https://github.com/alindeman/upgradingtorails4/releases/tag/v1.1.0.

I followed the directions, and got things working, except for this error: `rake aborted! uninitialized constant Rails::SubTestTask`.

The error occurs when I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, and when I run `git push heroku master`.

After I ran `git push heroku master`, it caused [my site](http://www.collegeanswerz.com/) to be down. How can I fix this error, and get my site back up?

UPDATE: Here are some heroku logs. I'm not sure what other information is relevant.

```
2014-01-19T04:21:17.711128+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-01-19T04:21:23.293242+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 10646 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-01-19T04:21:24.362457+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2014-01-19T04:21:25.944038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-01-19T04:21:25.959784+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-19T04:23:01.936377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/wofford/academics/professors/how-strong-is-the-alumni-network host=www.collegeanswerz.com request_id=0f280641-e72c-47f3-922c-054256214579 fwd="180.76.6.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-19T04:25:06.914297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/robots.txt host=www.collegeanswerz.com request_id=176cd299-7f1c-4985-9195-289874e45ffa fwd="66.249.66.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-19T04:25:07.045522+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/southern-illinois-university-carbondale/academics/classes/what-was-your-least-favorite-class host=www.collegeanswerz.com request_id=45c36f78-742f-4a08-9b9a-351b2bf27d0f fwd="66.249.66.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
# require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Collegeanswers
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

**development.rb**

```
Collegeanswers::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

end
```

**production.rb**

```
Collegeanswers::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Add the fonts path
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

   # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( about_college.css college_pages.css colleges.css essay_list.css 
  essays.css home.css layout.css static_pages.css tldr.css college_pages.js essays.js home.js static_pages.js favicon.ico .svg .eot .woff .ttf)

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'baci.lindsaar.net',
    :user_name            => 'azerner3@gmail.com',
    :password             => 'ahdumzurnurthre',
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

  config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"

end
```

**test.rb**

```
Collegeanswers::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
end
```

**failed rake task output**

```
~/collegeanswerz >>  rake rails:update
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rails::SubTestTask
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-perftest-0.0.3/lib/rails/perftest/railties/testing.tasks:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-perftest-0.0.3/lib/rails/perftest/railties/testing.tasks:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rails-perftest-0.0.3/lib/rails/perftest/railtie.rb:8:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `instance_exec'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `each'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:201:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:243:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:17:in `each'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:17:in `each'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:243:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:446:in `load_tasks'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
~/collegeanswerz >>
```

**update**

```
~/collegeanswerz >>  rake rails:update
    conflict  config/boot.rb
Overwrite /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/config/boot.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] bundle install
Y - yes, overwrite
n - no, do not overwrite
a - all, overwrite this and all others
q - quit, abort
d - diff, show the differences between the old and the new
h - help, show this help
Overwrite /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/config/boot.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] a
       force  config/boot.rb
       exist  config
    conflict  config/routes.rb
       force  config/routes.rb
    conflict  config/application.rb
       force  config/application.rb
    conflict  config/environment.rb
       force  config/environment.rb
       exist  config/environments
    conflict  config/environments/development.rb
       force  config/environments/development.rb
    conflict  config/environments/production.rb
       force  config/environments/production.rb
    conflict  config/environments/test.rb
       force  config/environments/test.rb
       exist  config/initializers
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
    conflict  config/initializers/inflections.rb
       force  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
    conflict  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
       force  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
    conflict  config/initializers/session_store.rb
       force  config/initializers/session_store.rb
    conflict  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
       force  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
       exist  config/locales
    conflict  config/locales/en.yml
       force  config/locales/en.yml
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
~/collegeanswerz >>  rake rails:update
   identical  config/boot.rb
       exist  config
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/application.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
       exist  config/environments
   identical  config/environments/development.rb
   identical  config/environments/production.rb
   identical  config/environments/test.rb
       exist  config/initializers
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
    conflict  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
Overwrite /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/config/initializers/secret_token.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] a
       force  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
   identical  config/initializers/session_store.rb
   identical  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
       exist  config/locales
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
       exist  bin
   identical  bin/bundle
   identical  bin/rails
   identical  bin/rake
~/collegeanswerz >>  rake rails:update
   identical  config/boot.rb
       exist  config
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/application.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
       exist  config/environments
   identical  config/environments/development.rb
   identical  config/environments/production.rb
   identical  config/environments/test.rb
       exist  config/initializers
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
    conflict  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
Overwrite /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/config/initializers/secret_token.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] a
       force  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
   identical  config/initializers/session_store.rb
   identical  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
       exist  config/locales
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
       exist  bin
   identical  bin/bundle
   identical  bin/rails
   identical  bin/rake
~/collegeanswerz >>  rake rails:update
   identical  config/boot.rb
       exist  config
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/application.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
       exist  config/environments
   identical  config/environments/development.rb
   identical  config/environments/production.rb
   identical  config/environments/test.rb
       exist  config/initializers
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
    conflict  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
Overwrite /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/config/initializers/secret_token.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] a
       force  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
   identical  config/initializers/session_store.rb
   identical  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
       exist  config/locales
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
       exist  bin
   identical  bin/bundle
   identical  bin/rails
   identical  bin/rake
~/collegeanswerz >>  bundle install
Using rake (10.1.1)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.4)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Using activesupport (4.0.2)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.2)
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.2)
Using actionpack-action_caching (1.0.0)
Using actionpack-page_caching (1.0.2)
Using actionpack-xml_parser (1.0.1)
Using activemodel (4.0.2)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.1)
Using activerecord (4.0.2)
Using bundler (1.5.2)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.2)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.10.1)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Using rails (4.0.2)
Using actionview-encoded_mail_to (1.0.4)
Using activerecord-session_store (0.0.1)
Using rails-observers (0.1.2)
Using activeresource (4.0.0)
Using annotate (2.5.0)
Using excon (0.31.0)
Using formatador (0.2.4)
Using net-ssh (2.7.0)
Using net-scp (1.1.2)
Using mini_portile (0.5.2)
Using nokogiri (1.6.1)
Using ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
Using fog (1.19.0)
Using asset_sync (1.0.0)
Using sass (3.2.13)
Using bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.0)
Using chart-js-rails (0.0.6)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (2.0.2)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
Using dynamic_form (1.1.4)
Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
Using fontello-rails (0.2.0)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using multi_xml (0.5.5)
Using httparty (0.12.0)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using jquery-tablesorter (1.9.5)
Using turbolinks (2.2.0)
Using jquery-turbolinks (2.0.1)
Using jquery-ui-rails (4.1.1)
Using jquery-ui-themes (0.0.11)
Using protected_attributes (1.0.3)
Using rails-perftest (0.0.3)
Using terminal-table (1.4.5)
Using rails4_upgrade (0.5.0)
Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
Using ruby-prof (0.14.2)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.8)
Using test-unit (2.5.5)
Using uglifier (2.4.0)
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
~/collegeanswerz >>  bundle exec rake assets:precompile
I, [2014-01-19T12:35:27.559511 #45119]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/public/assets/PTC55F-8a51a8dbd99ebb64038e5bc5d889e8de.ttf
I, [2014-01-19T12:35:27.603802 #45119]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/public/assets/PTC75F-67e3622fa715992a353cf8e9aacabfaa.ttf
I, [2014-01-19T12:35:27.645882 #45119]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/public/assets/PTN57F-d8ef42f92a175dc6266e65be28770e40.ttf
I, [2014-01-19T12:35:27.689838 #45119]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/public/assets/PTN77F-e7f569a81079fe2197f6e0f0530a1242.ttf
I, [2014-01-19T12:35:27.748504 #45119]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/public/assets/PTS55F-df874aeb0825a39cd66881f24804c5a4.ttf
I, [2014-01-19T12:35:27.836106 #45119]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/public/assets/PTS56F-58bf799abff6c2cc0891f78a7f29ce90.ttf
I, [2014-01-19T12:35:27.952892 #45119]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/public/assets/PTS75F-96b0ec122b6968fcac0399137ab4ce44.ttf
```

and then it ended with...

```
I, [2014-01-19T12:37:19.312625 #45119]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/adamzerner/collegeanswerz/public/assets/jquery-ui/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240-261647ac915575f3981ded254ae8d43e.png
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
rake aborted!
Fog provider can't be blank, Fog directory can't be blank
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/asset_sync-1.0.0/lib/asset_sync/asset_sync.rb:48:in `with_config'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/asset_sync-1.0.0/lib/asset_sync/asset_sync.rb:28:in `sync'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/asset_sync-1.0.0/lib/tasks/asset_sync.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/asset_sync-1.0.0/lib/tasks/asset_sync.rake:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:sync
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
~/collegeanswerz >>
```

**update 2**

```
 I, [2014-01-19T17:51:31.171362 #1823]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d25c5b42-f835-4294-b974-e70e2831b580/public/assets/jquery-ui/ui-icons_888888_256x240-ce584ffa171c3ea9a018cf0d7bec65c8.png
       I, [2014-01-19T17:51:31.174172 #1823]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d25c5b42-f835-4294-b974-e70e2831b580/public/assets/jquery-ui/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240-747e96029e8dedcabc224e5f7d1f2ede.png
       [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
       rake aborted!
       Fog provider can't be blank, Fog directory can't be blank
       /tmp/build_d25c5b42-f835-4294-b974-e70e2831b580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/asset_sync-1.0.0/lib/asset_sync/asset_sync.rb:48:in `with_config'
       /tmp/build_d25c5b42-f835-4294-b974-e70e2831b580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/asset_sync-1.0.0/lib/asset_sync/asset_sync.rb:28:in `sync'
       /tmp/build_d25c5b42-f835-4294-b974-e70e2831b580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/asset_sync-1.0.0/lib/tasks/asset_sync.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_d25c5b42-f835-4294-b974-e70e2831b580/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/asset_sync-1.0.0/lib/tasks/asset_sync.rake:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:sync
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:fast-reaches-9399.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:fast-reaches-9399.git'
~/collegeanswerz >>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rails::SubTestTask` is a task defined for testing.  But you're trying to deploy to production.  It sounds to me like somewhere you're trying to include Rails testing libraries where they are not in the bundle causing that task to not be defined.  Have you checked your code for any references to `Rails::SubTestTask`?

If you can't run `rake` locally, it's a pretty good bet it won't run on Heroku.  Maybe you could add in the error logs when you run rake and it fails with the `uninitialized constant`

Comment: I found this in my Gemfile: `# because uninitialized constant Rails::SubTestTask
gem 'ruby-prof', group: :test
gem 'test-unit', group: :test`. I ran `bundle install` and then tried the things the guy below you recommended, but it still didn't work. I'm not sure what those gems are, or whether or not I should have them. I didn't see `Rails::SubTestTask` anywhere else in my code. 

What do you mean by "add in the error logs"?

Comment: it's hard to read in the comments... is the `gem 'ruby-prof'` bit in a comment?  or is it active?  As for the error logs - you suggested that when you run `rake rails:update:bin` you get an error, right?  I'd like to see the full error stack from running that command.

Comment: So should I delete them, or just take away `group: :test`?

Comment: I think you should have ruby-prof inside the test group.  That's my guess.  All the stuff that is in test should *not* be included on Heroku.

Comment: I put it inside the test group, and `rake rails:update` didn't work. Then I commented that stuff all out, and it still didn't work.

Comment: can you post the output of the rake task that failed?

Comment: Yea, I just added it.

Comment: Cool - do you have `rails-perftest` in your gem list?  if so, try moving it into the test group (or commenting it out... just to see) and running rake again.  It looks like that gem may be the culprit

Comment: I think good stuff is happening... see the update to my question. Actually, it ended with bad stuff (a new problem?).

Comment: Yep - now you're into new territory... i might just start a different answer as the chat's getting long, but now my guess is that your Fog credentials aren't setup right on your local machine.  There maybe an enviroment variable or something that is used in your config to start up Fog and that may not be set for you locally.  You could check your config from heroku with `heroku config --app=<my app name>` and see what's out there.  And see if any of them look like FOG config things.

Comment: `~/collegeanswerz >>  heroku config --app=collegeanswerz
 !    App not found`. That doesn't look good. I don't know what Fog is, do you have an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: I also get something bad when I try to push to heroku. See update 2.

Comment: As long as rake is not working locally, you'll probably have no luck getting it to work on heroku, so i'd focus on getting your local version running properly.  Fog is a meta-cloud storage wrapper.  It allows you to store files to S3 and other external services.  https://github.com/fog/fog - those services need credentials which is *probably* what your missing.  As for the app not found, you probably have the wrong name.  You can run `git remote -v` and the remote called heroku will show you the app name.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I'm on to a new issue now; you fixed the `Rails::SubTestTask `. Now I got `bundle exec rake assets:precompile ` to work, but when I run `git push heroku master`, it tries to run `rake assets:precompile`, and gives me this error `rake aborted!
       Fog provider can't be blank, Fog directory can't be blank`. I ran `export FOG_PROVIDER ` and `export FOG_DIRECTORY ` before, which allowed `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to work. I just can't get `git push heroku master to work`. I'll ask a new question though.

Answer (score 1):

In your local copy try running this:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

Or with bundler:

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

This will generate the required bin stubs for you. Commit them to your repository and push everything to heroku.

If you've not run it before, you might want to run `rake rails:update` to perform all of the update actions.

Options available from the `rake -T` output:

```
rake rails:update                       # Update configs and some other initially generated files (or use just update:configs, update:bin, or update:application_controller)
```

UPDATE:

Sounds like you've got old Rails 3 files mixed up with your project causing you errors.

You should create a blank new Rails 4 app and go through each of the generated files comparing them to your own. Particularly `application.rb` and the various environment config override files.

Comment: All 3 of those were aborted because of the same issue: `rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rails::SubTestTask`

Comment: Sounds like you have some old rails 3 stuff in your configs. Try comparing them to the default rails 4 files generated with a new project.

Comment: I'm afraid to do that because I don't know what I'm doing, and I may mess something else up. I can't tell the difference between config differences due to rails 3, or due to something unique about my app. So would you mind taking a look at my config files? I posted them.

Comment: Jon is right - you should make a new app and check for differences in the environment config files.. that doesn't require any upfront changes to your current app.  see also http://blog.barbershoplabs.com/blog/2013/02/27/upgrading-from-rails-32-to-rails-40

Comment: Looks like you ran the update rake task and overwrote any conflicts. An upshot to this is the error you're now seeing: `Fog provider can't be blank, Fog directory can't be blank`. You might need to add back some config entries which are specific to your app. Using `git diff` might help (or whatever versioning system you use).